# OpenBLAS sgemm_oncopy error on CentOS6.5

Tags: java, linux, centos6.5, openblas

I have compiled OpenBlas0.2.14 on linux, and I used the OpenBlas library in my CNN code，when I submit the code into server(CentOS6.5, gcc4.4.7,g++4.4.7, glibc2.12), I got the following error:

```
    # An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    # SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fb75a5fc840, pid=1270, tid=140425791407872
    #
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.3-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C [libtest.so+0x1a840] sgemm_oncopy+0x40
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /home/test/hs_err_pid1270.log
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    # http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

However,in my CentOS6.5 (the same config for gcc,g++,glibc as the server),it has no problem,how did this happen,could anybody help me?